# EmbjerJS vs BackboneJS vs JavascriptMVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, ember.js, javascriptmvc

My this question is about not learning or asking the basic structure and changes among all of them, its just about having the most strong criteria of all you GURUs who pretended the another framework over to one.

I know this question had been asked by lot of people before but this time, I want to go in different perspective. Seems like, I made a bit research over the Google to know what all the peoples make in the comparison. In the end I got,

**BackBone**

- Lightest in framework weight as low as 5.5KB.
- Lack the documentation as based over this [Link](http://backbonefu.com/2011/09/knockout-vs-javascriptmvc-vs-backbone/)
- Follow strict MVC rules.
- To make it modular, you need to configure with AMD
- Focuses _underscore (framework library) to kickoff

**JavaScript MVC**

- Rich UI Components
- Heavy framework.
- Low frustration level.
- Normal Documentation.
- Provides core entities for testing
- Powered by Steal to use by Command Line
- Ofcourse MVC
- Just loads 2 files in the DOM
- Own 4 different templating engines.

**EmberJS**

- More then BackBoneJs. Just made to fill all the gapes that Backbone left
- 43K in size. Provides helper library for everything so less code
- Can be used with AMD to make it modular.
- Not enough popular with more documentation.
- Use Handlebar templating.

These are some of the points and every framework has it's own characteristics. Now, the point comes, which one is good if we're going to use them for Hybrid Mobile Application?

Think a while, I'm using PhoneGap & jQuery Mobile and now to make my code expandable later on and to give a perfect hierarchy to the application, which is the most suitable framework for the mobile application development?

It'd be by Speed, Hierarchy, Reliability, Load time, Ajax Calls (Helper stuff) and related.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what type of answer you're expecting, and also not sure if this question can be answered objectively. All these frameworks are suited for mobile SPA apps, but it all depends on how you implement the app.

Comment: Sir, ofcourse but do you think we wrote 10 modules and every module have 5 controllers and every controller have 3 actions? The big file and code structure. In this sense, which will be fine. Code less, Do more. Have the best processing speed.

Comment: I inspected backboneJS on chrome inspector and got that it loads all of the files we created like controllers, views and all. However, JMVC just loaded 2 files . I want suggestion in the similar senses

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: According to you, best javascript MVC framework to choose from Backbone, Ember & JMVC for mobile :) This is my question. It will help me

Answer (score 0):

Look also at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

[Knockout.js vs Backbone.js (vs ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js-vs)

My personal opinion is knockout with mapping plugin.

Best arguments for this opinion in my case was  a) that Knockout don't requires to use their classes as superclasses for models and b) code with Knockout is more laconic.

But BackBone is good too.

Comment: As what I think, knockoutJs is not MVC? its MVVM?

Comment: Yep. You have models with pure business logic, view-models that can be generated in runtime by mapping plugin and views is your html with additional binding attributes.

Comment: In my opinion Templating in KnockOut is not great, and definitely not as good as Ember with Handlebars or Backbone with Underscore. Haven't used JSMVC tho

Comment: knockout wrap the code on the HTML views? Is it good approach if you want to apply modular architecture?

Comment: My code functionality is for mobile application (Hybrid) and for this, I'll have lots of modules that will be plugged and play. How can you manage your hierarchy with Knockout?

Comment: Hamza Waqas, yep it good approach if you want to apply modular architecture. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html for example

Comment: >> In my opinion Templating in KnockOut is not great ////

You can use Knockout with ANY template engines. Examples of usage with underscore & jquery.template available here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

I used Knockout with Jade and everything is ok.

Comment: Okay, If I used AMD then it will bootstrap the application and still load all the class files to the DOM right? Don't you think it will be load to the application (mobile) ?

Comment: Hamza Waqas, if you use AMD modules with requireJs, you can compile your js to minified file, see http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Comment: So it means, rather then going with MVC, I may go with knockout MVVP pattern using requirejs / spine for AMD?

Comment: Yep, you can. In client-side JS applications MVP is more appropriate then traditionally used in backend MVC. MVVM (not MVVP as you said) approach also is designed specially for that case. But at all it's a matter of taste. Use approach that you like better.

Comment: Imho: Knockout just looks more simple and needs less efforts to work with it.

Comment: Okay, that's a great stuff. I'm gonna have a R&D Over the knockoutJS to follow the same approach. Thanks